# Spring Boot detect lost connection to GemFire

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

Does Spring Data GemFire provide any way to detect lost connection to GemFire Locator or Server from client-side application? I want to trigger an event to send an alert to inform user and then send request to other application to resend the information when connection is up.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data for VMware GemFire (SDG) does not in/directly (depending on your perspective) provide an API or means to detect when a client is disconnected from a cluster since GemFire/Geode already provides such mecahanisms.

See the `ClientMembershipListener` interface ([Javadoc](https://gemfire-910-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/management/membership/ClientMembershipListener.html)).

Use the `ClientMembership` ([Javadoc](https://gemfire-910-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/management/membership/ClientMembership.html)) class to register an implementation instance of the interface.